# we are facing issue while generating google meeting link for the event using google calendar API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We've integrated google calendar APIs but we are facing issue while generating google meeting link for the event. I guess it is due to we are not able to set AllowedConferenceSolutionTypes in calendar for google meet.

we are getting error

> "message" : "Invalid conference type value."

It seems like some permission issue while creating calendar or something else .

this is the code i've used to create event:

```
String calenderId = "xyz";
Event event = new Event().setSummary("Meeting");
event.setStart(getEventDateTime(meetingTime));
event.setEnd(getEventDateTime(meetingTime.plusHours(1)));

ConferenceData conferenceData = new ConferenceData();
CreateConferenceRequest conferenceRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest();
conferenceRequest.setRequestId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
conferenceRequest.setConferenceSolutionKey((new ConferenceSolutionKey()
.setType("hangoutsMeet")));
conferenceData.setCreateRequest(conferenceRequest);
event.setConferenceData(conferenceData);
try {
event = calendarService.events().insert(calenderId, event).setConferenceDataVersion(1).execute();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

return event;
```

We were expecting to create a google calendear Event with an Meets links. we are getting error "message" : "Invalid conference type value."  But when we do it without conferenceData a simple event gets created.

Comment: So is this still an issue, or have you find a way to create event with hangouts meet? Since we've beed working on google services in our workspace for years i know a thing or two and may be able to help :D

Comment: this is still an issue.

Comment: I've made an answer to insert some additional code and links.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a [calendar.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/get?apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22primary%22%7D) on that calendar it will tell you what conference type the user has configured for that calendar.

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"j3g2ipQvsbvz0_YlxYi3Ml2Fd7A\"",
 "id": "[REDACTED]",
 "summary": "Linda Lawton ",
 "description": "test",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
 "conferenceProperties": {
  "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
   "hangoutsMeet"
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: If that doesnt help let me know and i will test your code in the morning.

Comment: conferenceProperties is null for calendar.get

Comment: Wow i dont think i have ever seen a conference type null.  I wonder if you can update the calendar and set it

Comment: I think it's more of a configuration issue as you correctly pointed out. But we are not able to figure that out. I have tried to reach out to you through your profile.

Answer (score 0):

So basically if you are experiencing error like shown below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid",
        "message": "Invalid conference data."
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid conference data."
  }
}
```

in my experience, the cause may be described here:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars#resource

Look at field `allowedConferenceSolutionTypes`. Make a request to one of the calendars that you are trying to insert an event to, to check if solution type is allowed in the calendar.

Try removing explicit set of the solution type and let API set the default value:

```
ConferenceData conferenceData = new ConferenceData();
CreateConferenceRequest conferenceRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest();
conferenceRequest.setRequestId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
conferenceData.setCreateRequest(conferenceRequest);
event.setConferenceData(conferenceData);
```

If it still causes an error, you need to allow this type in the calendar. To do so, make PATCH request as described here:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/patch

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}
```

And set the body:

```
{
  "conferenceProperties": {
    "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
      "hangoutsMeet"
    ]
  }
}
```

Than try again. If the accounts you are creating events/calendars on are domain accounts, consider creating new calendars for the purpose of managing automatic events, or set domain-wide option in the admin console.